# How to call the module pocketshinx within the module pocketsphinx for python?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pocketsphinx

## So I'm trying to use a method in the pocketsphinx.py within the pocketsphinx module folder, but it gives me an error of:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx'; 'pocketsphinx' is not a package

## I don't know what is going on because it works fine doing the same thing for sphinxbase. And 'import pocketsphinx' works, but doesn't input the exact method I need call decoder_default_config. Here is the code:

```
import pyaudio as py
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *
import glob
import os, sys
model=(r'C:\Users\ellag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model')
config = Decoder_default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(model, 'en-us\en-us'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(model, 'en-us\cmuict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-kws', os.path.join(model, 'kws_file'))
decoder = Decoder(config)
p = py.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=py.paInt16,channels=1,rate=16000,input=True)
stream.start_stream()
While True:
    buf=stream.read(1024)
    Decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    if Decoder.hyp() != None:
        print(seg.word, seg.prob)
        letter=seg.word()
```

Comment: It looks like the correct usage according to the docs at https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python. Could you be missing a dependency?

Comment: I just installed it with 'pip install pocketsphinx' do you know if there's something else that I need to do?

Comment: If you type `pip show pocketsphinx` it shows any dependencies you could be missing (something like swig?)

Comment: 'C:\Users\ellag>python -m pip show pocketsphinx
Name: pocketsphinx
Version: 0.1.15
Summary: Python interface to CMU Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx libraries
Home-page: https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python
Author: Dmitry Prazdnichnov
Author-email: dmitry@prazdnichnov.name
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\ellag\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:'                               It doesn't seem to show anything

Answer (score 1):

Try installing on terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install pocketsphinx
```